# WAMP or XAMPP for Windows XP Professional

Tags: xampp, wamp

I have Windows XP Professional as my OS.

Which of the following solutions is best?

- WAMP
- XAMPP
- Separate installation

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend WAMP, as it's very easy to set up.

XAMPP is more feature rich though, as it includes Tomcat, and a slightly newer version of PHP.

Here's a simple breakdown of what's included in each:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest that users go for XAMPP server.

**Reason for choosing XAMPP over WAMP**

1. ***XAMPP has a beginner friendly interface*** with simple on/off buttons to start Apache and MySQL services. Whereas the latter has more options but it's interface is jam-packed which proves confusing for beginners.
2. XAMPP supports FileZilla so you can easily upload your local work onto your online server. It also comes with TOMCAT and ***newer version of PHP ( recommended for PHP Programmers*** )
3. ***XAMPP has more extensions*** to it compared to wamp.

You can check out my article on [xampp and wamp comparison](http://www.tutorialgear.com/xampp-vs-wamp-which-one-is-best-for-you/) to get a more detailed understanding:

Answer (score 0):

Wamp, faster and more noob friendly. Easy to configure and easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is easier to use in my opinion, but XAMPP may be more feature-rich.

Seeing as you're asking the question, though, I'd recommend WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using [BitNami WampStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/wampstack). It is a free all-in-one installer that includes Apache, PHP, phpMyAdmin, MySQL and a GUI management tool for the servers.

It is similar to XAMPP, WAMPServer, etc. in that regard but with some differences: We keep it up to date (XAMPP is also kept fairly up to date, WAMPServer has not been updated since 2010 at the time of writing this posting). Also, any of the all-in-one Apache bundles are 
Windows specific. We are multiplatform, meaning that you can use the same environment across multiple operating systems (Mac, Linux, Windows). We find this very useful internally, since our designer works on Windows and the rest of us run on Linux or OS X.

Also, we have found that a lot users want to setup XAMPP for local development on top of Joomla!, Drupal or Wordpress for developing plugins, themes, etc. and that is why we created all-in-one packages that include Apache, MySQL, PHP and those applications [pre-installed](http://bitnami.org/stacks). We also have [Rails](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) and [Django](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) versions of the stacks if that's what you are developing on.

Give it a try (it is free!) and let us know what you think :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual-AMP & Visual-NMP, It is like the IIS,
Green portable, requires no installation. Stop related services that are running the program, you can move the directory.

Comment: Please post comment not in the answers section